# Share an instance over a call stack in C#

Tags: c#, callstack

Check the functions below, please:

```
public void DoJob()
{
    CheckPrivilege();
    DoJob2();
}

public void DoJob2()
{
    CheckPrivilege();
    DoJob3();
}
```

As you can see, if I call `DoJob()`, the `CheckPrivilege()` function runs twice. Sometimes I can call `DoJob2()` directly so I cannot remove `CheckPrivilege()` function from `DoJob2()`.

So I need to know that the `CheckPrivilege()` function is called in another function which is in same call stack.

That is, I want to share a Privilege object over a call stack.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: c# or c? Please take more time when posting a question. Also your question is unclear. I didn't downvote, so give me a reason for not doing so. Tell us what exactly is your goal, or you are not getting any presents from Santa.

Comment: i was just editing post, in c#, So as i sad i want to share an instance over a call stack. For example i want to store an instance in DoJob() function, and then in DoJob2() function i want to check is there any stored instance in call stack

Comment: What is the motivation for the question? Is the call expensive or are you just trying to avoid repeated code?

Comment: yes CheckPrivilege() is very expensive and in many function it is called. Sometimes it is executed 7-8 times and gives exact same result with the previous call

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways you could do it but 'sharing over a callstack' is not possible.  You could keep a state variable indicating if the current task has privileges or do something like this.

```
function void DoJob()
{
    CheckPrivilege();
    DoJob2(false);
}

function void DoJob2(bool doPrivCheck)
{
    if (doPrivCheck)
       CheckPrivilege();
    DoJob3();
}
```

Comment: CheckPrivilege() is called in many function. So i cannot pass doPrivCheck parameter over every function. Thats why i want to know , can i store this parameter in call stack.

Comment: @brtb can you store it as a property of the containing class these functions are in?

Comment: Just out of curiosity why can't you pass a variable on all calls?   Is it just a preference?  Otherwise you've got to store the result of the privilege check somewhere.  The stack is not the place to do it.  See @MartinSmith's comment.

Comment: @MartinSmith there are lots of classes.

Comment: @brtb well I guess technically you could do it. In a similar way to how `TransactionScope` works. Not sure how that works. Possibly thread local storage.

Answer (score 0):

Define 'internal' and 'external' interface functions.  The external functions do the privilege checking and can be called by anyone; the internal functions do not do the checking and should only be called by the implementation.

Treating your functions as the 'external' ones:

```
function void DoJob()
{
    CheckPrivilege();
    DoJob2_Internal();
}

function void DoJob2()
{
    CheckPrivilege();
    DoJob3_Internal();
}

function void DoJob2_Internal()
{
    DoJob3_Internal();
}
```

The principle applies to any language — I'm not a C# programmer so I can't tell you what specific features of C# would enforce the access controls or function visibility, or whether you have to rely on convention.